# Splitting each character object in multiples of data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, split, dataframe

This is my dataset below. It is a list of 10 data frames, and each data frame contains different elements. What I would like to do is to split the character objects within each data frame so that it would only display the numbers within the objects, not the letters. Because I'm going to test to see if the numbers in each data frame are even or odd after this, it would probably have to be turned into a vector of integers. So for example, for the first data frame, it would return 4. For the second data frame, it would return 8. For the third, it would return 4 12, etc etc.

```
$control
[1] "A4"

$control
[1] "G8"

$pq
[1] "A4"  "G12"

$docetaxel
[1] "G8"

$docetaxel_b
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8" 
[21] "B9"  "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"   "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4" 
[41] "D5"  "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9" 

$docetaxel
[1] "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1"  "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4" 
[21] "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9"  "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

$dactinomycin
[1] "E12"

$cisplatin
[1] "F8"

$cisplatin_b
[1] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" "A5" "A6"

$cisplatin
[1] "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8"  "B9"  "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1" 
[21] "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4"  "D5"  "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9" 
[41] "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1"  "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5" 
[61] "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9"  "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1" 
[81] "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your list contains data frames, at least not as shown.  Here is an approach to get rid of the characters.  This is on a small subset of your data.

```
lst <- list(control="G8", pq=c("A4", "G12"), docetaxel=c("G8"), docetaxel_b=c("A1", "A2"))
lapply(lst, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", x)))
```

produces:

```
$control
[1] 8

$pq
[1]  4 12

$docetaxel
[1] 8

$docetaxel_b
[1] 1 2
```

Basically, we just get rid of anything that isn't a number (`"[^0-9]"`) with `gsub`, and then convert to numeric.  You can easily modify the function inside the `lapply` to check whether the values are even or odd with something like `%% 2`, though without knowing exactly what you want to know (count of evens, presence of odds, etc.), I can't provide further guidance.

Comment: Thanks! So I did that, then I did lapply(lst, function(x) x%%2==0). Then I did lapply(lst, function(x) all(x)) to see which ones only had even numbers. Now, I want to get rid of the data frames that have returned TRUE for the last function I applied. So if they have only even numbers, I want to delete them from the original list of 10 data frames. How would I do that?

Comment: Assuming your original data are in `lst`, and your final data with the true and false are in `lst2`, then `lst[unlist(lst2)]`

Comment: That gives me the ones that are TRUE (the ones that only have even numbers). How can I tweak that so I can get it to return the ones that are FALSE (the ones that do not have just even numbers)?

Comment: @hj14 `lst[!unlist(lst2)]`